# How to call cplex .mod and .data from Java

Tags: java, cplex

I have an optimization problem modelled and written in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio. I want to call .mod and .dat from Java. I found some example to do it. However, I got some error.

My code is shown below. I also added all cplex and opl library

```
package cplexJava;
import ilog.concert.*;
import ilog.cplex.*;
import ilog.opl.*;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              model();
    }
     public static void model() {
          int status = 127;                                                       

              IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(true);                                     
              IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();                             
              IloOplErrorHandler errHandler = oplF.createOplErrorHandler();         
              IloOplModelSource modelSource = oplF.createOplModelSource("D:/Cplex project/Example_2/Example_2.mod");                                            
              IloOplSettings settings = oplF.createOplSettings(errHandler);         
              IloOplModelDefinition def = oplF.createOplModelDefinition(modelSource,settings);
              IloCplex cplex = oplF.createCplex();                                  
              cplex.setOut(null);                                                   
              IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);                    
              IloOplDataSource dataSource = oplF.createOplDataSource("D:/Cplex project/Example_2/Example_2.dat");                                            
              opl.addDataSource(dataSource);                                        
              opl.generate();                                                       
              if (cplex.solve())                                                    
              {                                                                     
                  System.out.println("OBJECTIVE: " + opl.getCplex().getObjValue()); 
                  opl.postProcess();                                                
                  opl.printSolution(System.out);                                    
              }                                                                     
              else                                                                  
              {                                                                     
                  System.out.println("No solution!");                               
              }                                                                     
              oplF.end();                                                           
                      status = 0;                                                   

            System.exit(status);
     }
}
```

In my code, the errors came from from  `oplF.createCplex()` and  `cplex.solve()`. When I tried to run it, this is the error I got.
[image]
I could not figure out why I got the errors from  `oplF.createCplex()` and  `cplex.solve()` although I already added the `cplex` and `opl` library

Answer (score 1):

Actually your IDE tells you what the problem is: There are possible IloExceptions thrown and you do not handle them. You need to either surround your code with a try catch block, or your main-method should have a "throws IloException" in the signature:

```
package cplexJava;
import ilog.concert.*;
import ilog.cplex.*;
import ilog.opl.*;


public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        model();
    }
    public static void model() {
        int status = 127;
        try {

            IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(true);
            IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();
            IloOplErrorHandler errHandler = oplF.createOplErrorHandler();
            IloOplModelSource modelSource = oplF.createOplModelSource("D:/Cplex project/Example_2/Example_2.mod");
            IloOplSettings settings = oplF.createOplSettings(errHandler);
            IloOplModelDefinition def = oplF.createOplModelDefinition(modelSource,settings);
            IloCplex cplex = oplF.createCplex();
            cplex.setOut(null);
            IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);
            IloOplDataSource dataSource = oplF.createOplDataSource("D:/Cplex project/Example_2/Example_2.dat");
            opl.addDataSource(dataSource);
            opl.generate();
            if (cplex.solve())
            {
                System.out.println("OBJECTIVE: " + opl.getCplex().getObjValue());
                opl.postProcess();
                opl.printSolution(System.out);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No solution!");
            }
            oplF.end();
        } catch (IloException ilx) {
            // log error message or something like that
        }
        status = 0;

        System.exit(status);
    }
}
```

And please use class names with upper case first letter and package names with all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

For the OPL Java API, you should only need [oplall.jar](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplinterfaces/topics/opl_interf_intro_java_deploy.html).

**SETUP**

On my x86-64 Linux machine with Eclipse 3.6, this is done, like so (hopefully it's similar for you):

1. Right click on your Java Project and select Properties
2. Select "Java Build Path" on the left and the Libraries tab on the right
3. Click on the "Add External JARs..." button and select `COS_INSTALL_DIR/opl/lib/oplall.jar` (where `COS_INSTALL_DIR` is the location where you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio)
4. Click OK

One more thing to do is make sure that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is set to `COS_INSTALL_DIR/opl/bin/x86-64_linux`. (**NOTE**: On Windows, I think you should set the `PATH` environment variable instead.) You can set this in Eclipse, like so:

1. Select "Run > Run Configurations..." in the menu
2. On the left, select your java application
3. On the right, select the Environment tab and click on the "New..." button
4. Enter `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the Name field (try `PATH` on Windows)
5. Enter `COS_INSTALL_DIR/opl/bin/x86-64_linux` in the Value field (again, where `COS_INSTALL_DIR` is the location where you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio)
6. Click OK

**FIX COMPILER ERRORS**

Once you have that set up, you'll probably notice that you are still getting compiler errors (the little red squiggle lines indicate this). Hover your mouse over the those and you'll be presented with a list of quick fixes: 1) add throws declaration; 2) Surround with try/catch. Pick one of those to fix the issue. After all of the red squiggly lines are gone you should be able to run your program.

If you're not familiar with fixing compiler errors in Eclipse, maybe [this](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/15wi/eclipse_tutorial/compiling.shtml) Eclipse tutorial with help. Sometimes you have to select "Project > Clean" to force a recompile.

Comment: Thank so much Rkersh. I did exactly what you suggested, but it still does not solve my problem.   My oplall.jar path is  C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\opl\lib\oplall.jar, and my library path is C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\opl\bin\x64_win64.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what the remaining problems are (or open a new question). Also: remove the `import ilog.cplex.*;` and `import `ilog.concert.*;` statements.

Comment: @DanielJunglas 
I have removed the import ilog.cplex.*; and ilog.concert. However, I still have red compiler errors. Also, I could not run it as shown in the above post.

Comment: You are facing some standard Java error messages (unrelated to CPLEX). The  functions that produce compilation errors may raise an exception of type `ilog.concert.IloException`. So you have to either catch those exceptions or declare your functions to throw them. A simple fix to get things compiling would be to add `throws ilog.concert.IloException` to your function declarations. A better thing would probably be to catch those exceptions and handle them in some way. The best would be of course to get back to a Java course/book, read about exceptions and understand why you got the errors

Comment: I added a bit more to the **FIX COMPILER ERRORS** section in my answer above. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: While @DanielJunglas is completely right, I still wonder why people tend to give advice on how to do something completely different with paths and more instead of giving any help to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the the same problem.

After some trial and error I realized that the correct name is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` for macos.

[Referral link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/working_environment/topics/opl_working_env_variables_unix.html)